# Give an example of a bounded set $X$ and a continuous function $f$ for which inf $f(X) >0$ does not hold.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

For the first part, I proved the statement below.

> Let $X$ be a compact metric space and $f:X\to \mathbb{R}$ be continuous with $f(x)>0$ for each $x\in X$. Prove inf{$f(x):x\in X$}$>0$.

This is the question below.

> Give an example of a bounded set $X$ and a continuous function $f$ for which the above
> property does not hold.

My guess is just a trivial mapping $f:(0,1)\to \mathbb{R}$ with $x\mapsto x$. This map satisfies the above conditions, but infimum is $0$. Is this ok? Since my answer is too trivial, I'm not sure if I'm alright.

Comment: yes, that example is fine.

Comment: Ok, thank you!!